# ELB health check failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb

> an instance was taken out of service in response to a ELB system
>   health check failure.

I hit the health check endpoint with my browser and it returns fine, but I'm getting the above message.

How can I debug this?

I've looked at `instant settings => Get System Logs` and nginx logs,

- edit

nginx has

`- [27/Mar/2020:05:35:42 +0000]  "GET /littlehome/heartbeat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 2.920 2.920 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
- [27/Mar/2020:05:35:42 +0000]  "GET /littlehome/heartbeat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 2.858 2.856 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`

it returned 200 for sure..

and still aws think it received `502`

```
{
    "Target": {
        "Id": "i-085e8dffe8781f876",
        "Port": 80
    },
    "HealthCheckPort": "80",
    "TargetHealth": {
        "State": "unhealthy",
        "Reason": "Target.ResponseCodeMismatch",
        "Description": "Health checks failed with these codes: [502]"
    }
},
```

[image]

Comment: What are your settings for the health check? path, port, protocol?

Comment: @Marcin I've added a bit more info

Comment: @Marcin added heath check setting

Comment: And if you disable HCs, everything works as intended with ELB?

Comment: can't find where to disable HC @Marcin

Comment: Which ELB specificly you use? ALB, NLB or CLB?

Comment: ALB (type: application)

Comment: I see you right. Cant disable. It can only by done for lambda targets in alb.

Comment: i was reading nginx/access.log and aws elbv2 describe-target-health and saw aws decides ` "Description": "Health checks failed with these codes: [502]"` before nginx receives any request, shortly after aws decides the target is unhealthy i saw the nginx log for HC requests..

Comment: ok found the solution... https://engineering.telia.no/blog/troubleshooting-fargate-health-check#3-does-the-service-start-responding-quickly-enough-after-a-start thanks for help @Marcin

Comment: Do you use ASG? Maybe have to add/change a [grace period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html) so that the health checks are not immedietly performed?

Comment: Ah yes, so it was ASG and grace period after all:-), though your question does not indicate that you use ASG.

Comment: yeah can u make it an answer, so i can close it

Comment: Thanks. I added the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was that [grace period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html) in Auto Scaling Group was too short. The solution was to increase it.